# Memory error on using data generator in keras

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, dataset, data-augmentation

I am using the following augmentations on dataset of size 9 GB:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
    samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
    samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
    zca_whitening=True,  # apply ZCA whitening
    rotation_range=30,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
    width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
    height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
    horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
    vertical_flip=True)  # randomly flip images
datagen.fit(a)

model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(a,b, batch_size=32),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(a) / 32, epochs=epochs, class_weight = sclass_weight, validation_data = [c, d],callbacks = [MetricsCheckpoint('logs')])
```

When the code comes to the `datagen.fit`, I get into memory error ( the code doesn't even go into training)

I have 50 gb ram and am training it on a K80 with a batch size of 32, so don't think that will be a problem.

It works fine when I comment all the augmentations.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are running out of memory, because the computation are done on the GPU have a look at your house memory

Comment: As I said earlier, gpu has 12 GB memory, and a batch size of 32 shouldn't be a problem right

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49458905/6524169 this might help

Comment: Are you using colab? due to using K80.

Comment: @Media I don't think so as he has 50 gigs main mem

Comment: @Media No, we got it here at workplace. We use a scheduler so we can request 50 gigs memory. Hence the k80 as slaves. Hope its clear now

Comment: Maybe you can put your entire code. Maybe, it can help.

Comment: I get the same issue. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the root cause for this is that `zca_whitening` is set to `True`. According to the answer from the keras-collaborator rragundez in this [related Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/issues/55), there is no work-around for it, except disabling ZCA whitening:

> This is known problem with the ZCA method. There is no real immediate way around it. The problem is with the calculation of the sigma matrix which is a dot product.

The other alternative to disabling it would be to use images with a smaller resolution. But I suppose that's rarely a practical solution.